# auto-generate bit.ly urls in php wont work

Tags: php

i have a small problem (i think).

my website generates a link and thad link i want to get shortened.

this is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST["sub"])) {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
    $r = rand(1,100000);
    $filename = $r . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  if (file_exists("upload/" . $filename)) {
    echo "<center>";
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. Please Rename your file and try again.</center><br>";
  }
else
  {
  $link="$baseurl/upload/" . $filename;
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $filename);
  echo "<center>Direct Download link: <a href=\"$link\">$link</a></center><br>";
  }
 }
}

include("main.html");
?>
```

i want to shorten the outcome of "$link" to be shortened by bit.ly.
so i did some research and found this useful script:

```
function make_bitly_url($url,$login,$appkey,$format = 'xml',$version = '2.0.1')
{
    //create the URL
    $bitly = 'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version='.$version.'&longUrl='.urlencode($url).'&login='.$login.'&apiKey='.$appkey.'&format='.$format;

//get the url
//could also use cURL here
$response = file_get_contents($bitly);

//parse depending on desired format
if(strtolower($format) == 'json')
{
    $json = @json_decode($response,true);
    return $json['results'][$url]['shortUrl'];
}
else //xml
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    return 'http://bit.ly/'.$xml->results->nodeKeyVal->hash;
}
}

/* usage */
$short = make_bitly_url('$link','dsfser','R_5aafdd2f8d67f78150e52ffbd0613519','json');
echo 'The short URL is:  '.$short;
```

so what i dont get is if i put in this line: make_bitly_url('>>>$link<<<','dsfser','R_5aafdd2f8d67f78150e52ffbd0613519','json'); $link it doesn't take the link from te code above but if i use google.nl it works.

can somebody look what i do wrong?

THANX!

Comment: Change `$short = make_bitly_url('$link','dsfser','R_5aafdd2f8d67f78150e52ffbd0613519','json');` to `$short = make_bitly_url($link,'dsfser','R_5aafdd2f8d67f78150e52ffbd0613519','json');`

Using '$var' will prevent the $var to be replaced by your string.

Comment: thank you for your solution! i'm not so far in php so im still learning! thanks!

Comment: Check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Read the "single quoted" and the "double quoted" links.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to echo the variable $link that is surrounded by single quotes.

You should use quotes surrounding strings, not variables. However, if you use double quotes you can echo directly variables inside them, however, personally I would recommend you to always use single quotes and separate your variables with dots.

```
 <?php
 $var = 'variable';
 //echo string
 echo 'test this is a ';
 echo $var;
 echo '!';

 //previous 2 echos show: "test this is a variable!", however you could concatenate it like this:
 echo 'test this is a '.$var.'!';
 ?>
```

**SOLUTION:**

Change:

```
$short = make_bitly_url('$link','dsfser','R_5aafdd2f8d67f78150e52ffbd0613519','json');
```

to:

```
$short = make_bitly_url($link,'dsfser','R_5aafdd2f8d67f78150e52ffbd0613519','json');
```